# Constraintlayout animation dosent work

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

For some reason i cant get the constraintset animation todo anything. Nothing happens when the code is called. Even if i change the id of the `tab`

```
private fun moveNavigationBall(tab: BottombarItemView) {
    val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()

    constraintSet.clone(cl_bottombar_view_main)
    constraintSet.connect(v_bottom_bar_circle_indicator.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, tab.id, ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
    constraintSet.connect(v_bottom_bar_circle_indicator.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, tab.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);
    constraintSet.connect(v_bottom_bar_circle_indicator.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT, tab.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
    constraintSet.connect(v_bottom_bar_circle_indicator.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, tab.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
    constraintSet.applyTo(cl_bottombar_view_main)

    val transition = ChangeBounds()
    transition.interpolator = OvershootInterpolator()
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cl_bottombar_view_main, transition)
}
```

This is called when a button is pressed. The tabs is different depending on which button is pressed. What i want todo is move the `v_bottom_bar_circle_indicator` to the middle of each tab

**The view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/cl_bottombar_view_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <com.main.toucanmvp.mvp.components.bottombar.bottombaritem.BottombarItemView
        android:id="@+id/biv_home"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:bivBackground="@drawable/drawable_navigation_background_left"
        app:bivIcon="@drawable/ic_home"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/biv_search"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.main.toucanmvp.mvp.components.bottombar.bottombaritem.BottombarItemView
        android:id="@+id/biv_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:bivIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/biv_clan"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/biv_home"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.main.toucanmvp.mvp.components.bottombar.bottombaritem.BottombarItemView
        android:id="@+id/biv_clan"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:bivIcon="@drawable/ic_crown"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/biv_news"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/biv_search"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.main.toucanmvp.mvp.components.bottombar.bottombaritem.BottombarItemView
        android:id="@+id/biv_news"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:bivIcon="@drawable/ic_news"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/biv_profile"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/biv_clan"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.main.toucanmvp.mvp.components.bottombar.bottombaritem.BottombarItemView
        android:id="@+id/biv_profile"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:bivBackground="@drawable/drawable_navigation_background_right"
        app:bivIcon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/biv_news"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/v_bottom_bar_circle_indicator"
        android:layout_width="34dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_circle_navigation_bar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/biv_home"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/biv_home"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/biv_home"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/biv_home"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in order to animate the change of constraints you need to put

```
constraintSet.applyTo(cl_bottombar_view_main)
```

after

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(cl_bottombar_view_main, transition)
```

Secondly, in your XML layout file you are using `start` and `end` constraints for the view you want to animate (`v_bottom_bar_circle_indicator`) but in your code you are using `ConstraintSet.LEFT` and `ConstraintSet.RIGHT`, which are different. You need to change these to `ConstraintSet.START` and `ConstraintSet.END` respectively.

Third thing, which may or may not matter in this case, is that you are setting a margin of `0` as the last argument of each `connect()` function. The `ConstraintSet` documentation says that the margin must be a positive number, so it may not behave as expected when set to `0`. I suggest using the signature without the margin parameter in this case.

Comment: I was in the beginning to find out that left and right was something wrong with. Because i tested bottom and top and it only reacted to those on further testing.

Thanks a lot! You saved me the biggest headache today.